# Two versions of gems in production rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, gemfile, gemset

I think i have some issues with my gemfile in production, as it differs from my development, which i believe is causing my deployment (Capistrano) to fail, well at bundle install time at least

Development

```
actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.4)
capistrano (2.14.2, 2.12.0)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1, 0.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2, 1.3.3)
commonjs (0.2.6)
daemon_controller (1.1.2, 1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (0.9.1, 0.8.0)
devise (2.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.2, 1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.6.0, 1.3.1)
font-awesome-rails (3.0.2.0)
highline (1.6.16, 1.6.13)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1, 2.0.2)
json (1.7.7, 1.7.6)
less (2.3.1, 2.2.1)
less-rails (2.3.2, 2.2.3)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux, 3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
listen (0.7.3, 0.7.2)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.22, 1.19)
multi_json (1.7.2, 1.5.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nested_form (0.3.1, 0.3.0)
net-scp (1.1.0, 1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.1.1, 2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.6, 2.5.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.4.1, 3.1.4)
passenger (3.0.19, 3.0.14)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5, 1.4.4)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (10.0.4, 10.0.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0, 0.8.8)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12)
ref (1.0.4)
rmagick (2.13.2, 2.13.1)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1, 2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0, 2.11.1)
rspec-mocks (2.13.0, 2.11.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.0, 2.11.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sass (3.2.7, 3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
therubyracer (0.11.4, 0.10.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.6, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6, 2.1.1)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.33)
uglifier (1.3.0, 1.2.6)
warden (1.2.1)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

Production

```
actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.1.4, 1.1.3)
capistrano (2.12.0)
cocaine (0.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
commonjs (0.2.6)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (0.8.0)
devise (2.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.3.1)
font-awesome-rails (3.0.2.0)
highline (1.6.13)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.6)
less (2.2.1)
less-rails (2.2.3)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
listen (0.7.2)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nested_form (0.3.0)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.5.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.1.4)
passenger (3.0.14)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rb-inotify (0.8.8)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.1)
rspec-mocks (2.11.1)
rspec-rails (2.11.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.5, 1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
therubyracer (0.10.1)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.1)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.6)
warden (1.2.1)
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'mysql2'

#Devise Gem
gem "devise", "~> 2.2.3"

#for uploading files  
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'rmagick'

#Nested Form
gem "nested_form"

#need this for rails 3
gem 'rb-readline'

#Pagination
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'less-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

#js stuff:
gem 'execjs'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

#gem to allow running on ubuntu server
gem 'therubyracer'


group :development do
  gem 'rails-dev-boost', :git => 'git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git', :require => 'rails_development_boost'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.8.8'
end


group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  #adding database cleaner for tests
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end

# Deploy with Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano'

#run with passenger
  gem 'passenger'
```

The problem i am getting is when deploying the application cannot find the will_paginate gem. Am i correct in saying that it looks like i have two gemsets trying to work here? Im not quite sure, dont want to mess up my production environment so thought best to get some advice on this one

Comment: did you deploy with capistrano?

Comment: yes i did, ill add that to question

Comment: do you have `require "bundler/capistrano"` in your cap recipe?

Comment: i havent but i tried that and it didnt work, got error couldnt find bundler , how can i get my produciton gemset to match that of development, that may fix the issue i believe

Comment: Will ask here as well: What does your `Gemfile` look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is working in development environment in your machine, then I think you should push your `Gemfile.lock` along with your code and deploy the application. Then `bundle install` in your production environment also installs the same gems versions as in your development environment.

Comment: well in my production environment Gemfile.lock has will_paginate, so should i just run bundle install in production? sorry for all the questions

Comment: Which version that it has listed in the repository's Gemfile.lock? If you are using a gemset, remove the gemset, create a new gemset with same name, install bundler and run, bundle install. If necessary, you can fix your will_paginate gem version to be '3.0.4'(which is giving error, by leaving as '> 3.0.0').

Comment: ok so what i have done is in production specified a gemset so rvm use @global then ran bundle install, seems to work now, guess will have to wait until i deploy again to see if anything fails

Answer (score 1):

You need in your `deploy.rb`

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :bundle_cmd, '/path/to/bundle'
```

So bundler will install all necessary gems automatically.

Otherwise you need to do it manually.

Comment: thanks, silly question, the path/to/bundle where is this typically? ie what is the path/to/bundle? /Gemfile

Comment: some examples: `/home/user/.rbenv/shims/bundle`, `/home/user/.gems/bin/bundle`

Comment: dont have anything that looks like that, not that i can see..what is the manual way for now?

Comment: hang on in the root of my app i have /.bundle/config and in the config file is this ---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production  this isnt correct is it?

Comment: ok, and when looking in  production i have a shared folder but no reference to bundle anywhere or did removing the folder above resolve this issue do you think?

Comment: couldnt get your suggestions to work  so what i have done is in production specified a gemset so rvm use @global then ran bundle install, seems to work now, guess will have to wait until i deploy again to see if anything fails